# Ubuntu 16.04. How to open folder in midnight commander from nautilus

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nautilus, mc

I do open folder in mc from nautilus in the ubuntu 12.04 by right mouse button clicking. But in 16.04 I have no nautilus-open-terminal package in the Synaptic. Instead gnome-terminal is installed. So I have "Open in terminal" in the popup menu after right click in nautilus but have no "Open in midnight commander". Yes, I know about opening terminal and typing mc but I'm tooooo lazy...

Answer (score 1):

Edit menu and add a command "Open in midnight commander"; the command is `gnome-terminal -e mc`.

Comment: Super! Easy and do what I need!!

Answer (score 0):

More details how to edit menu. Install nautilus-actions package in Synaptic. Run the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool in terminal with `nautilus-actions-config-tool`. Add new action with the name ***Open in mc***. Enable only ***Display item in location context menu*** switch. Open Command tab. Set path to ***gnome-terminal -e mc*** and Working directory to ***%f***. At last you can unselect ***Create a root Nautilus-Action menu*** in the preference dialog if you prefer to have new commands in the same popup menu instead of submenu.